# What is debt in islam?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, debt

Is debt just a money or it is any object we took from someone? For example when I was kid about 11 years old, sometimes I took from my friends games. Now I have some games which are not mine but I don't know from whom I borrowed it, because latter on we split, everyone went in different school. Can i be in paradise if I don't return them?

Comment: Bruh imagine going to suffer for all eternity, having your skin seared by the flames of hell for it to only grow back and burn away again amongst other terrifying punishments, the least of which being forced into shoes of fire (forever) and all that for not returning gta 5 or whatever. Bruh

Comment: @UbaidHassan How does your comment attempt to answer the question being asked, Bruh?

Comment: according to https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment, one of things you cant do is answer a question with a comment, though what i said wasnt constructive lol

Answer (score -2):

Muhammad (s.a.s) once said:

> Lending is ten times better than giving money to beggers, because
>   beggers do have money, but lendees genuinely need it.

however he also said:

> The person who borrows something with the intention of not giving back
>   is a thief.

Due to your age at that time, I reckon it may just be fine.

Comment: Please cite the source for the claimed hadith.

Comment: What if I entered puberty at that age? And is debt just money or any object we borrow? I mean am I in debt right now?